# multiple input from users to save in database in one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I don't know how to describe what I am looking for but i can illustrate it with diagram which I drawn.

The first below here is 'user input' which will be in gridview and it will require users to input details. the (textbox) is a textbox and the details next to it is an input example.

```
User Inputs:

Items                 Quantity             Unit Price              Total
(textBox)abc         (textBox)2          (textBox) 100          (textBox) 200
(textBox)def         (textBox)1          (textBox) 150          (textBox) 150
```

After save button is clicked (I didn't show the button, sorry), the details will be saved in the database such as shown below 'save in database'.

```
Save in Database:

 ID            Items           Quantity      UnitPrice       Total
10001        Abc , def           2,1          100,150       200,150
```

And when the user wants to display the details, the details should show like in the below 'display results'.

```
Display Results:
ID:10001   
Items     Quantity     Unit Price     Total
Abc          2            100          200
def          1            150          150
```

I hope this explanation is understandable, I am quite poor in explaining and also in ASP.
please help me to code this out in C# or VB because I am out of option to do this. 
thank you so much.

code example:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Products(Name, ProductImage, OriginalPrice, DiscountPrice, Descriptions,StockQuantity, Category) VALUES (@Name, @ProdImage, @OriPrice, @DisPrice, @Descrp, @Quantity, @Category)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[7];

        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar,100);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ProdImage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@OriPrice", SqlDbType.Float );
        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@DisPrice", SqlDbType.Float );
        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@Descrp", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);

        param[0].Value = name;
        param[1].Value = image;
        param[2].Value = OriPrice;
        param[3].Value = disPrice;
        param[4].Value = description;
        param[5].Value = quantity;
        param[6].Value = Category;


        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

current code:

```
private string CreateRow(DataTable data, Int32 index, String ColumnName)
{
String[] quan =   data.Rows[0][ColumnName].ToString().Split(',');
if (quan.Length >= index)

return quan[index].ToString();
else
return "";
}
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SalesOrder WHERE ID = 10010";
DataSet DataFromDataBase = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SalesOrder WHERE ID = 10010", conn);
adp.Fill(DataFromDataBase);

DataTable TempData = new DataTable();
TempData.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
TempData.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", typeof(string));

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataRow row = TempData.NewRow();
    row[0] = CreateRow(DataFromDataBase, i, "Quantity");
    row[1] = CreateRow(DataFromDataBase , i, "UnitPrice");
    TempData.Rows.Add(row);
}
}
```

Comment: Why would you store it in this denormalized format, when both the input and the output are normalized?

Comment: which control you are using to display data? Grid View, repeater, data list or any other?

Comment: @peterLang, because i want the details to be under the same ID.

Comment: @Code Rider, gridview for the user input and listview (if possible) or just gridview for display results.

Comment: Why not split your primary key into two columns (`10001, 1` and `10001, 2`)? This could save you a lot of problems...

Comment: @Peter Lang, but then i have dynamic rows (more rows to be added in runtime for the users) so there will be more than two rows of textboxes sets to be added to the same primary key. that would be a problem in database later, right?

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L: No, this would actually be a lot easier with this approach. You would just add `10001, 3`, `10001, 4` and so on.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L Please check my new answer. It should help you.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L Mark it as answer if it helps you. It may help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DataFromDataBase** is a datatable in which you are getting your data from database.
At last you'll get data in your required format in **TempData**  Datatable.

you have to bind Grisview with **TempData** Datatable.

I have done this work with only two columns, you can change it according to your columns. I have taken maximum 5 as your maximum number of values in one field. you can modify according to your requirement.

```
   DataTable TempData = new DataTable();
    TempData.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
    TempData.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", typeof(string));

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = TempData.NewRow();
        row[0] = CreateRow(DataFromDataBase, i, "Quantity");
        row[1] = CreateRow(DataFromDataBase, i, "UnitPrice");
        TempData.Rows.Add(row);

    }

private string CreateRow(DataTable data, Int32 index, String ColumnName)
{
   String[] quan =   data.Rows[0][ColumnName].ToString().Split(',');
   if (quan.Length >= index)

       return quan[index].ToString();
   else
       return "";
}
```

If you are getting data in **DataSet** from database. you can pass parameter to **CreateRow** function as below

```
     CreateRow(  DataFromDataBase.Tables[0], i, "UnitPrice");
```

**EDIT**    like this you have to get data in dataset or datatable (your choice)

```
DataSet DataFromDataBase = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbdep;select * from tbemployee", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
    adp.Fill(DataFromDataBase);
```

Comment: Its exactly according to your requirement. Let me know, if you'll face any problem.

Comment: this code should be under the save button right? and how bout the connection and sql statements? where should i locate them?

Comment: no this code should go, where you want to bind the grid view. Where you are getting data from database on aspx page.

Comment: ,and the DataFromDatabase should be the name of my database or i should initialized it to the database columns?

Comment: hopefully, you will write a query "select * from table where blah blah".  you have to get result of this query in "DataFromDatabase" datatable or dataset.

Comment: check the EDIT part of my answer. I have something helpful for you.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L Ok. So mark it as answer. If it helps you to solve your problem. It may help others in future.

Comment: i updated the code in the current code section in my question. can you check it? is it suppose to be like that? so sorry, i'm bit new with asp so i am not so good with it.

Comment: yes fine, now you can bind other control after for loop with TempData.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L mark it as answer. I hope i have given you proper solution without changing your current code. Do you know how to mark an answer?

Comment: yup. i know. will let you know again if i couldn't manage to get the exact output. thank you.

Comment: but then, it is showing this two errors.
[(The best overloaded method match for 'Default2.CreateRow(System.Data.DataTable, int, string)' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Data.DataTable')]

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L sure, I'll give you proper solution.

Comment: uffff, dear you are passing the wrong parameter, at last of my answer i have written, how to handle it with dataset. please have a look on it.

Comment: but, i already put the dataset code as well. i don't get you i guess. :(

Comment: yup. no more errors. thank you. but why there is no results? do i have to add anything to the gridview?

Comment: set autogeneratecolumns="true" in gridview.

Comment: I can't help beyond this. It works ever with this code ( <asp:GridView ID="anyid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>).   have you bind your gridview or not. use this code. (anyid.DataSource = TempData; anyid.DataBind();)

Comment: hm, before you go, why does it shows this error 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' for this code [return quan[index].ToString()].

Comment: please use a break point to find out the exact problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5557y8b4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

the way you are saving the values is really unrealistic and denormalized.

you should save the values like:

```
 ID            Items           Quantity      UnitPrice       Total
10001           Abc                  2          100           200
10001            def                 1          150            150
```

and you can use following query in sql:

```
select * from table where ID = 10001
```

It will return you two rows in datatable or dataset(whatever you use). you can easily bind it with any control like GridView, Repeater and Datalist.

By this way you can easily reduce you code to display data in your required format.

may it'll help you.

Comment: thank you so much. but how to save the values in the way you suggest? should i make it like Kamil Kransinski suggested?

Comment: this is a possible solution but if you might want to create composite primary key or create a UniqueId column so that your records are unique enough to update/delete. this would depend on what data access you are using (SqlCommands and readers, Datasets or Enity Framework)

Comment: the best way to save multiple rows at same time is using XML or bulk insert. can you provide some code example which you are using right now to save values?

Comment: @Kamil Krasinski, which data access you recommend? i am familiar with SqlCommands and readers.

Comment: http://codeandscript.blogspot.in/2012/06/insert-bulk-data-in-sql-using-openxml.html     check this  way to save multiple rows at once in sqlserver. 
It should solve your problems.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L thanks. anyways can you have only two values with comma? like 1,2 and 100, 250, or it can be vary?

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L if you are using Sql Server 2005+ I would recommend to have a look at entity framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134816 and linq

Comment: @Code Rider, it can be vary.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L okay, its fine. Let me make a solution for you. In which you  don't have to change you existing code and you won't need any other way to handle it.

Comment: @Kamil Krasinski, yup using. SQL Server 2008. is it a video? the page does not show video..

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L yes it was a video. they are a good start but to view msdn's videos you might need silverlight on your machine. to get working basic knowledge of EF, I'd recommend Beth Massi's videos on EF: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/08/26/new-how-do-i-videos-released-on-entity-framework-wpf.aspx. they are on WPF but principals are the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is possible in code, but would require custom concatenation and splitting when reading and writing to storage.

However, I would suggest that you normalize your data and create 2 tables:

**IdHeader**

HeaderId
CreatedOn
UserName
etc

**IdDetail**

HeaderId
Item
Quantity
UnitPrice
Total
etc

Comment: yes it is possible, but its not realistic to use such kind of code.

Comment: @Kamil Kransinski, you mean to make foreign key of IDHeader to IDDetails table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them under the same ID why not add another column, say OrderId?

Comment: @Yuri Kashtanow, after adding, which do u suggest, make it as Foreign key from another table or composite key?

Comment: Well, the best way is to create another table for Orders and then make this orderId a foreign key, as described in other answers... This would make it easy to manage it in the future, so I would suggest that.

Otherwise if lazy - just let it be a composite.